# Taking user input and appending it to a tuple? Python

Tags: python

So basically I'm trying to create a list of movies with their budgets, but I don't know how to take the input and place it into a tuple

```
movie_list = ()
while True:
    title = print("Enter movie: ")
    budget = print("Enter budget: ")
    movie_list.append(title, budget)
    user = input("Would you like to add more movies? (y) or (n)").upper
    if user == 'N':
        break
    if user != 'N' and 'Y':
        print("Invalid entry, please re-enter!\nContinue? (y) or (n)")
print(movie_list)
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable objects.  You will want to create movie_list as movie_list = list(), and then create an embedded list of lists.  Eg. movie_list.append([title, budget])

Comment: What is *exact* the problem/issue you're encountering?  For example, the errors with your input? Hint- just ```.append(( a, b))```

Comment: `()` is not a tuple, use  built-in `tuple()`. But in this case I would use a `list`  since you are using `append`

Comment: You can't append to a `tuple`, since tuples are immutable.  You can either create a new tuple, or you can use a `list`, later converting it to a `tuple` if desired.

Comment: this conditional check is terrible... `user != 'N' and 'Y':` use smt like `user not in {'N', 'Y'}` which is more readable

Comment: @cards Consider this: *a = (); print(type(a))* which shows that a pair of left/right parentheses represents an empty tuple

Comment: You should be using a list rather than a tuple to gather these data. Even better, use a dictionary keyed on movie and with budget as the associated value. Also, *input().upper* is not going to do what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Tuples don't handle appending well. But lists do:

```py
movie_list = []   # make a list, not a tuple
while True:
    title = print("Enter movie: ")
    budget = print("Enter budget: ")
    movie_list.append( (title, budget) ) # append a 2-tuple to your list, rather than calling `append` with two arguments
    user = input("Would you like to add more movies? (y) or (n)").upper
    if user == 'N':
        break
    if user != 'N' and 'Y':
        print("Invalid entry, please re-enter!\nContinue? (y) or (n)")
print(movie_list)
```

Comment: @cards it transforms a string to uppercase. Allows for "y" and "Y" to be accepted as input

Comment: then you should call it, `.upper()`

Comment: Both work in python. But I agree a function syntax is nicer.

Comment: @0xRyN `.upper` returns the method so you will end up in a oo-_loop_

Answer (score 0):

You can’t add elements to a tuple due to their immutable property. You can’t append for tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable in Python. You cannot add to a tuple.

A tuple is not a data structure like a list or an array. It's meant to hold a group of values together, not a list of the same kind of values.

I think I get what you want, my guess would be that you want a list of tuples. In that case, just change the first line variable to be a list.

I improved your code so your logic works:

```py
movie_list = []  # movie_list is a list
while True:
    title = input("Enter movie: ")  # Use input() to get user input
    budget = input("Enter budget: ")
    movie_list.append((title, budget))  # Append a tuple to the list

    # movie_list is now a list of tuples

    # Check if the user wants to add another movie
    more = None
    # Loop until the user enters a valid response
    while True:
        more = input("Add another? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if more in ("Y", "N"):
            break
        print("Invalid input")

    # If the user doesn't want to add another movie, break out of the loop
    if more == "N":
        break

    # Else, continue the loop


print(movie_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite new to the programming scene so I still have a lot to learn. This is what I was looking for

Comment: Glad it helped! If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Coding apart, to write any program, first one should know the purpose of the program and its outcome. It would be better, if you can show here what the exact output you want, out of the created or appended list. As far as I understood your requirement, you should go with dictionary concept so that you can store data as pairs, like, movie and its budget.

{"movie":budget}

While taking input of budget, be sure whether you want to restrict the input value to an integer or you want to allow this as a string, like in crores. Hope this will help you.